# Google API coordinates changed whether country/zipcode was included in the input

Tags: geocoding

A users inputs the below and address 1 returns different coordinates to address 2&3. A slight change in coordinates can have an impact.

Below are just dummy examples

1. 20 W Shallow Hill St, New York, NY 86305
2. 20 W Shallow Hill St, New York, NY 86305, USA
3. 20 W Shallow Hill St, New York, NY, USA

Any suggestions on how to limit these variation? Is it always preferred to have the country in the string?

One thought was to just educate the user to be consistent in their formatting.